# How to make images can be cached by client browsers via varnish?

Tags: caching, varnish, cache-control

body:

- I add the Cache-Control http header when vcl_deliver, like:
  [image]
- I found the chrome broswer's debug console:
  [image]
- I think the response code should be **304**, not **304 Not Modified**，I hope the browser caches the image(don't request the varnish) but it doesn't work.

Could you suggest me?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Expires` response header set to some time in future.
In the current state caching works, browser is allowed to hold cached copy for one year.
But as there is no expiration, it has to validate content on server side, possibly with conditional request header such as `If-None-Match` (if you are using `E-Tag` in response header) or `If-Modified-Since` (if use are using `Last-Modified`).

You can add `Expires` header with following vcl snippet (borrowed from https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleSetExpires):

```
set beresp.http.Expires = "" + (now + beresp.ttl);
```

However, I don't see `If-Modified-Since` in request headers. And that's strange as it should be there to allow varnish to respond with 304.

PS> `304` or `304 Not Modified` doesn't matter, it's ok now.